# Converting Null to 0

Tags: sql-server

I'm running this query against my DB and it's returning null on the scripts for month and week; However, isn't returning null when I run it for the year totals.

What is it about the week and month that isn't working while the one for the year is?  I'm thinking I totally botched the code but cant find where.

Week:

```
declare @today datetime = '2015-10-15' 
set nocount on; 

select [Week Total] = convert(decimal(18,2), sum(isnull([Total],0)))
from [Accounting].[dbo].[Pay] 
where [AccountingDate] <= @today and 
[AccountingDate] > dateadd(week, -1, @today);
```

Month:

```
declare @today datetime = '2015-10-15'
set nocount on; 

select [Month Total] = convert(decimal(18,2), sum(isnull([Total],0)))
from [Accounting].[dbo].[Pay] 
where [AccountingDate] <= @today and 
[AccountingDate] > dateadd(month, -1, @today);
```

Year:

```
declare @today datetime = '2015-10-15'
set nocount on;

select [Year Total] = convert(decimal(18,2), sum(isnull([Total],0)))
from [Accounting].[dbo].[Pay]
where [AccountingDate] <= @today and
[AccountingDate] > dateadd(year, -1, @today);
```

Made changes to show consistency.

Comment: Is there any data for this week and this month?

Comment: or TotalJackpotAmount vs Total?

Comment: You do notice that you are referencing different tables and columns in those queries, right?

Comment: Yes there is data for this week and month.  The I fixed the inconsistencies that was a result from coping over my scripts and not prof reading after making changes to remove identifying information.

If I run the scripts using a date exactly a year ago I get data returned how I expected too.  Only an issue when I try to do it using current date.

Comment: Awesome, turns about the db I was using is a month behind from the live systems that's why its breaking when I try to use a current date! Thanks!